# Import Eclipse plugins from Luna to Neon?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

I've always used File > Import > Install > From Existing Installation to bring over plugins from old Eclipse releases. However, in Neon, it doesn't work when I select my Luna directory.

I used this process:

1. mv eclipse eclipse.luna
2. Unzip Neon jee package
3. edit eclipse/eclipse.ini as needed
4. Start Neon
5. File > Import > Install > From Existing Installation
6. Next
7. Browse to Luna directory
8. OK

Error message says "Select at least one available element to be installed". There are no items listed in the list box area.

Is this a known issue in Neon? I don't see any relevant errors in eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.log

Comment: what did you edit in eclipse/eclipse.ini? There shouldn't be anything to change. In any case, I believe this user-story is supposed to work, so you can open a bug report to http://bugs.eclipse.org to hope it get fixed, or at least better handle with more helpful messages, soon.

Comment: I edited it to specify the -vm argument to select my JDK, and increase the max RAM setting (-Xmx)

Comment: I reported bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499905

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my Eclipse bug report, this is explicitly forbidden in Neon.

Source bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=490515